# How to retrieve user's birthday data via Facebook Graph API 2.8?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wonder if it's possible to obtain user's birthday via Facebook Graph API 2.8. I am using Graph API Explorer and it requests me to put `{user-id}`. Can I retrieve the birthday information only knowing the user's name and surname? How should I specify the query? For example, `GET/v2.8/"NameSurname"`

All my attepts to write a request are finishing with this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: \"NameSurname\"",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "FRE/aemzTRL"
  }
```

}

**UPDATE:**

I was able to only retrieve the data for myself using something like `me?fields=name,email,gender`. But is it possible to get the same data for another person knowing his/her name and surname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get data of users who authorized your App, by using their Access Token with `/me?fields=name,email,gender,birthday`

You need to authorize them with the `email` and `user_birthday` permissions, btw.

Comment: Let's say I have the authorization of that user. Do I understand correctly that the only thing that I should do is to substitute my access token by the token of that user?